# Vertical align lists elements

Tags: html, css

I want to vertical align all li elements (also multi-line) and it seems big problem for me ;/
Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5bDVw/1/
I would appreciate any help

Comment: Well, if you can explain what the problem *is* that'd help us to help you..?

Comment: The problem is that text in the drop down menu is don't v-align (Look at "Kredyty" or "Oferta inwestycyjna")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem vertically aligned to me? I'm therefor guessing you want to vertically align the text in the drop down menu items? If so, set line-height so that it is equal to the element height:

```
#top-content  li li a { line-height:38px; }
```

Update:

Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/PfY5N/
I think it works as you want it to. I removed the 38px height measurements you had and added a padding on the anchor element instead. However, I strongly recommend cleaning that css up somewhat, it's kind of messy ;)

Comment: It's good but only if text has got one line... It doesn't work for 2 line text.